# Is there any way to extract asserts from C files?

Tags: c, regex, bash, gcc

Is there a simple way to extract the inside of the assert functions from C files?

For example -

```
assert(cred->keytab == NULL);

/*
assert(1==1);
*/
```

The output should be -

```
cred->keytab == NULL
```

I'm looking for something like xgettext just for the assert functions.

Comment: You can probably use your compiler to preprocess the code to get rid of the comments, then grep

Comment: `grep -Eo '\((.+->.+)\)' file.c | sed 's/[()]//g'` maybe...

Answer (score 2):

Just use the preprocessor, and it will appear on stderr:

---

```
#undef assert(x)

int main(void)
{
int x=1;

assert(x==1);
return 0;
}
```

---

```
$ cc -Wall assertz.c
 warning: extra tokens at end of #undef directive [enabled by default]
 #undef assert(x)
              ^
assertz.c: In function ‘main’:
assertz.c:8:1: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘assert’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
 assert(x==1);
 ^
```

Answer (score 2):

What about letting the processor get rid of the comments?

```
gcc -E prog.c -fpreprocessed | \
  sed -re 's/^.*assert[ \t]*[(](.*)[)].*$/\1/;t;d'
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with `awk`(in case you ok with it), this will also take care of in case assert function is coming inside comments it will skip it.

```
awk '
/^\/\/assert/{
  next
}
/assert/ && !found{
  match($0,/\(.*\)/)
  print substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-2)
  next
}
/^\/*/{
  found=1
  next
}
/^\*\//{
  found=""
}
'  Input_file
```

Comment: This can't work, because the comments in C could span multiple lines. This doesn't handle that

Comment: What if the comments are of type `//assert(foo==bar);`

Comment: @Inian, how about now? I added condition of checking `//assert`, just went by your given example, sorry but I am not a C language person, let me know.

Comment: I wouldn't do this way! ideal would be to pre-process the to remove the commented code and then do the match

Comment: @Inian that would be even more difficult. Like, on my system, `cc -E prog.c` turns `assert(1 == 2)` into `((1 == 2) ? ((void) (0)) : __assert2("prog.c", 4, __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, "1 == 2"));`